# Show selectedObject with PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

What is the correct way to show the selected object of a property Grid?

In Visual Studio they use a combobox. Is there a default setting that I can change to enable this or something like it?

Short Video Explanation: http://youtu.be/uI5crr_9hZA

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, the `Properties` windows is actually a pane having `ComboBox` and `PropertyGrid` controls (checked with `UISpy` tool).

If you want to have similar functionality, you could add a `ToolStripComboBox` to the `PropertyGrid` toolbar using its controls collection. Add the object collection to this combo and in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler set the `SelectedObject` of `PropertyGrid` to the selected item in the combo.

Sample code:

```
ToolStripComboBox objectDropDown = new ToolStripComboBox();
foreach (Control item in propertyGrid1.Controls)
{
    ToolStrip toolstrip = item as ToolStrip;
    if (toolstrip != null)
    {
        toolstrip.Items.Add(objectDropDown);
    }
}
```